# Laggy transition in one way only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I created a simple, pure CSS, dropdown menu. I'm facing a wierd lag problem. When the menu is rolling-down the transition is smooth, but in the opposite direction there's an about 1 second lag before the animation begins.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch">
<label for="switch" id="switch-button">Click me!</label>

<div id="txt">
<p>Menu element 1</p>
<p>Menu element 2</p>
<p>Menu element 3</p>
<p>Menu element 4</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#switch        { display: none; }
#switch-button { display: block; }
#txt           { max-height: 400px; }

#switch ~ #txt {
    transition: 1s max-height 0s;
}
#switch:not(:checked) ~ #txt {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#switch:checked ~ #txt {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s1237n9h/8/

Problem occurs in: Chrome, Firefox, Android browser, Edge.

Comment: Neither the code you posted, nor the link provided [https://jsfiddle.net/s1237n9h/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/s1237n9h/3/) produce the described effect in any of the listed browsers, except for AB (which I can't test right now). Please provide a [mcve] of the described issue. In it's current form, it's not ***verifiable***.

Comment: Please check newest revision: https://jsfiddle.net/s1237n9h/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay is due to the fact you're transitioning from `max-height: 400px` to `max-height: 0` but your container only has `72px` in height.

Therefore you are not able to observe the animation from `400px` to `72px`, but only after `max-height` is animated below the actual `height` of your element. If you match the `height` of the element and the `max-height` you will observe the transition in full, without any *visual* delay.

Comment: How can I get rid of this lag without setting `max-height: 72px`? This value can vary due to avaliable fonts in the browser...

Comment: Currently there's no pure CSS solution for animating `max-height` dynamically from `100%` to `0`. Or, if it exists, I'm unaware of it. But workarounds exist. One option is to use a relatively positioned wrapper with `overflow:hidden` and animate the top property of the only child from `0` to `-100%`. You could also animate `transform:scale()` from `1` to `0`. But, as a practical solution, I find myself relying on `velocity.js` (which also ensures a 60fps rate on all animations), because it's smart enough to calculate `100%` in px for `max-height` and enable smooth transitions to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `transition-delay: -.5s;`
to

```
#switch:not(:checked) ~ #txt {
```

Result:

```
  #switch:not(:checked) ~ #txt {
        max-height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: 1s max-height 0s;
        -moz-transition: 1s max-height 0s;
        transition: 1s max-height 0s;
    transition-delay: -.5s;
  }
```

Comment: It indeed works. Could you please explain from the theoretical point of view why it is necessary, because I can't see any logical explanation. Thank you!

Comment: To be totally honest I have no idea why it is that way, it seems that it for some reason adds .5 delay to the transition but as said I can't see why, as I am a beginner myself. I hope someone with more experience will be able to explain it :)